# When & How the Intermediate Certificates will be available to Browser

Tags: ssl-certificate, pki

I am aware that **Root CAs** will publish their **Root Certificates** to all **Browser vendors** (Google, Microsoft, Mozilla etc...). Then when we install any browser in our machine, it will also load all the Root CAs during the installation process.

My question is how the **Intermediate Certificates** of the **Intermediate CAs** will be loaded to our browser? **When & how the browser will get the Intermediate Certificates** so that the browser can **validate the signature on the Intermediate Certificate** when it receive from the Web Server during the **hand-shake process**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server must send any intermediate certificates to the browser along with its own certificate.

[RFC 5246, section 7.4.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) says:

> certificate_list
> This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
> independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
> certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
> assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
> validate it in any case.

TLS 1.3 and other protocols have a similar concept - certificates are sent as chains, not individually.